# Update records from one table to the other MySQL non-unique columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in two databases. Database 1 which is named db1 which has table addresses. Database 2 which is name db2 which has table counties.

The structure is as follows:

addresses:

```
_id | address | countyID | cityID | stateID | postalCode | countryID
```

counties:

```
_id | stateID | countyName
```

Currently the countyID in the addresses table has the county name. What I need to do is take the value that is in addresses.countyID find it in counties and select the countyID from the counties table and then update the addresses table with the countyID.

End result, the addresses.countyID needs to have the countyID not the countyName.

Thank you, any help would be great. I have been trying all kind of things. I tried simple `WHERE` and `JOIN` but nothing seems to be working. I am using MySQL as my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up creating a new table from the select results.

```
CREATE TABLE AddressesCounties 
SELECT db1.addresses._id, db1.addresses.address, db2.counties._id, db1.addresses.cityID, db1.addresses.stateID, db1.addresses.postalCode, db1.addresses.countryID 
WHERE db1.addresses.countyID = db2.counties.countyName;
```

This was a bit easier to create this temp table than altering real data. This way I could run my SELECT command and test my results before applying them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

UPDATE DB1
SET COUNTYID = (SELECT ID FROM DB2 INNER JOIN DB1 ON DB1.COUNTYID=DB2.ID)

I'm not sure which column in DB2 you're matching on, the more I read your question, the more confused I get! :)

Comment: I have to match db1.countyID ON db2.countyName. So would I change the syntax to this: UPDATE DB1 SET COUNTYID = (SELECT ID FROM DB2 INNER JOIN DB1 ON DB1.COUNTYID = DB2.COUNTYNAME)

Comment: Yep that should do it, as long as ID is the column you want to use to replace DB1.COUNTYID